# spec validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The following tests are all passing *except* the "it { should be_valid }" lines in 'describe "sent treatings" do' and 'describe "received treatings" do'

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Treating do

  let(:requestee) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:requestor) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { @received_treating = requestee.received_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum") }
  before { @sent_treating = requestor.sent_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum") }

  describe "sent treatings" do
    subject { @sent_treating }
      it { should respond_to(:intro) }
      it { should respond_to(:requestor_id) }
      it { should respond_to(:requestor) }
      its(:requestor) { should == requestor }
      it { should be_valid }
  end

  describe "received treatings" do
    subject { @received_treating }
      it { should respond_to(:intro) }
      it { should respond_to(:requestee_id) }
      it { should respond_to(:requestee) }
      its(:requestee) { should == requestee }
      it { should be_valid }
  end

  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to requestor_id" do
      expect do
        Treating.new(requestor_id: requestor.id)
      end.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end

    it "should not allow access to requestee_id" do
      expect do
        Treating.new(requestee_id: requestee.id)
      end.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end

  describe "when requestor_id is not present" do
    before { @sent_treating.requestor_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when requestee_id is not present" do
    before { @received_treating.requestee_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

here is the error:

```
Failures:

  1) Treating sent treatings 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/treating_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Treating received treatings 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/treating_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

lastly, my user.rb model:

```
class Treating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :intro, :proposed_date, :proposed_location

  validates :requestor_id, presence: true
  validates :requestee_id, presence: true

    belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :requestee, class_name: "User"

end
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the subject of your test? a Meating or a Treating as in your code? Could you post its source, too, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this test you have two meetings and set only one of the two ids of each of them in the fixture:

```
before { @received_treating = requestee.received_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum") }
before { @sent_treating = requestor.sent_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum") }
```

assuming user is the same as in your last question,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :sent_meetings, :foreign_key => "requestor_id", :class_name => "Meeting"
  has_many :received_meetings, :foreign_key => "requestee_id", :class_name => "Meeting"
```

@received_treating should have an requestee_id but not an requester_id (has never been assigned anywhere!) and @sent_treating has a requestor_id.

so again, for the same reasons as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750715/rspec-failing-validations/11750936), the validation fails, as both have only one of the two ids requested in the validation set.

What is the behaviour that you expect? If you want to build up the n:m relationship to the users, you will have to specify the second user at some point. Maybe you mean a fixture like that:

```
before do 
  @treating = requestor.sent_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum")
  @treating.requestee = requestee
end
```

maybe you even want to create a custom setter in Treating

```
def send_to(user)
  requestee = user
end
```

then you could write something like

```
before { @sent_treating = requestor.sent_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum").send_to(requestee) }
```

That gives you a Treating with both ids set.

Comment: thank you (meetings from 1st question do == treatings). before do sent_treating.requestee = requestee and received_treating.requestor = requestor fixed the problem. appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use before(:each) block

```
before(:each) {
    @received_treating = requestee.received_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum") 
    @sent_treating = requestor.sent_treatings.build(intro: "Lorem ipsum") 
}
```